# Is there a quicker way to collapse Art boards in Sketch app?

Tags: sketch-app

I want to collapse all the Art boards I have in **one go**, not just by manually closing them down.

Is there a short cut or a option in Sketch which enables me to do this?

[image]

End result:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So. After a lot of searching, digging I finally found the solution ....

here it is :

[image]

Comment: I'm not seeing this icon in my version of Sketch (55.2), so not sure if it was removed.

As noted in one of the [other answers](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/110176/74438), there is a menu item: View > Layers List > Collapse All Groups.

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I get annoyed by having to click that little layer icon at the bottom of the layer list *every time*.

Instead, I've set a custom keyboard shortcut. (This approach will work for adding *any* keyboard shortcut that accesses a menu item from the Sketch Application menu.)

1. Start by going to to: **System Preferences > Keyboard > App Shortcuts**.
2. Then, click the **+ icon**.

When you click the plus icon you'll see the following prompt:

[image: Prompt you see when clicking the + icon]

3. Type the name of the command exactly as it is found in the Sketch application menu, in this case, *Show Layers*.
4. Then, type in the shortcut you desire for the command. (For hiding and showing layers, I've found that option + command + g works well, but choose what ever combo of keys works for you.)
5. Click 'Save'.

Now, in Sketch, if you navigate to the application menu go to **View > Layers List**, you should now see a shortcut next to the menu item 'Show Layers' that looks like this:

[image: Shortcut added!]

Now, instead of having to click that annoying little icon every time, you have a super quick keyboard shortcut that does the same thing.

(P.S. This approach works for *all* applications on the Mac, you just have to make sure the shortcut name matches the menu item of the application exactly.)

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

There is indeed a shortcut for it: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution Collapse Artboards and Groups: https://medium.com/@namba/collapse-artboards-and-groups-for-sketch-3-1-31ee8e784604

Comment: SE requests that answer not rely on external resources. While this may answer the question it may be flagged as spam and it will be removed if so. Please make an edit to include the relative information if you'd like the answer to stay.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a shortcut, but i find it easier to just search help <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> navigate with arrow keys and hit enter. I use it for lots of less used actions or actions for which i donot remember shortcut.

[image: Help Search to collapse layer]

Answer (score 0):

In Sketch 74 (and probably earlier versions) it is now located under:
View → Sidebar → Collapse All Groups

This collapses all groups & artboards.